# Размер long в С++

Tags: типы-данных, c++

Читаю [книгу Лафоре](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/5410595/) там сказано следующее

> Мы  уже  говорили,  что  размер  переменных  типа  int  является  аппаратно-зависимым.  Переменные  типов  long  и  short,  напротив,  имеют  фиксированный  размер,  не  зависящий  от 
> используемой системы. 
> Размер  типа  long  всегда  равен  4  байтам  и  совпадает  с  размером  типа  int  в  слу- 
> чае  32-разрядных  систем,  подобных  Windows.  Это  означает,  что  диапазон  значений 
> типа  long  совпадает  с  диапазоном  типа  int:  от  -2  147  483  648  до  2  147  483  647.

Однако раньше я всегда слышал, что апрпаратно-зависимыми являются все типы кроме char. 
Кто же прав?

Comment: И даже char аппаратно-зависим. На некоторых TMS-ах 16 бит, а не 8 (как мы все привыкли).

Также обратите внимание, sizeof дает размер любого типа *в char-ах* (не обязательно 8-ми битных).

А 64-bit (8 байт) long это обычное явление для 64-бит машин.

В Linux принято, что размер long совпадает с размером машинного слова, хранящего указатель.

Comment: @avp можно ссылку на инфу о char 16 и sizeof ?

Comment: @ProkletyiPirat, [вот здесь](http://hashcode.ru/questions/118221) как-то уже обсуждали этот вопрос.

Comment: По стандарту sizeof(char) всегда равен 1, и это именно 1 байт. Но дело в том, что стандарт дает свое определение байта и гарантирует только то, что байт способен вместить не менее 8-ми бит.

Comment: @Andy_Reed, если отвечать конкретно на Ваш вопрос, то Лафоре не прав (и уже давно).

Answer (score 3):

Короче на всех актуальных и не очень платформах (x86, x86-64, ARM и других) дела обстоят так:

```
sizeof(char)==1
sizeof(short)==2
sizeof(int)==4
sizeof(long long)==8
```

С экзотическими платформами, где это не так, я не знаком. Если не пишешь под древние компьютеры или под микроконтроллеры, то считай, что это всегда так.
 Для спокойствия можешь вставить это в static_assert или использовать типы uint8_t и подобные из какого-то стандартного заголовка.

А вот размер long как раз меняется: на Windows он всегда 4 байта, а на большинстве других платформ, включая Linux его размер совпадает с разрядностью платформы.

Comment: Достаточно подробно этот вопрос рассмотрен [здесь, на SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/384502/what-is-the-bit-size-of-long-on-64-bit-windows).

Comment: Я вроде как раз это и читал пару лет назад, когда начал портировать свой движок на Linux.

Answer (score 2):

Стандарт гарантирует нижние границы типов, зависимых от основных (аппаратно-зависимых) - int и float.
Мне кажется, начудили с переводом. Имелось в виду, что sizeof(long) >= sizeof(int).

Стандарт (п.3.9.1.2):

> There are five standard signed integer
> types : “signed char”, “short int”,
> “int”, “long int”, and “long long
> int”. In this list, each type provides
> at least as much storage as those
> preceding it in the list. There may
> also be implementation-defined
> extended signed integer types. The
> standard and extended signed integer
> types are collectively called signed
> integer types. Plain ints have the
> natural size suggested by the
> architecture of the execution
> environment 44 ; the other signed
> integer types are provided to meet
> special needs.

Вольный перевод:

> Существует 5 основных знаковых целых
> типа: “signed char”, “short int”,
> “int”, “long int”, и “long long int”.
> В этом списке каждый тип занимает, по
> крайней мере, такой же объем памяти,
> что и предшествующий ему в том же
> списке. Также могут существовать
> завсимые от реализации расширенные
> знаковые целые типы. Основные и
> расшиеренные целые типы вместе
> называются знаковыми целыми типами.
> Простые целые типы (int) имеют
> естественный размер для платформы
> исполнения; другие знаковые целые типы
> предоставляются для особых нужд.